# expected initializer before ‘*’ token

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am trying to implement the code in the *Design Patterns* book.  I am getting the following error:

```
expected initializer before ‘*’ token
```

for this line:

```
static Singleton *Singleton::itsInstance = 0;
```

Here's the complete code.  I am using g++ 4.2.1 to try and compile this.

```
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton *instance();
protected:
    Singleton();
private:
    static Singleton *itsInstance;
}

static Singleton *Singleton::itsInstance = 0;

Singleton *Singleton::instance()
{
    if (!itsInstance)
    {
        itsInstance = new Singleton;
    }
    return itsInstance;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the class definition. Also you don't need the word `static` before the definition.

Comment: Seth is right.  But while we're piling on - you should probably cast `0` to a pointer before assigning it.

Comment: @BrianCain No casting needed when assigning from `NULL`, `0` or `nullptr`.

Comment: Remove "static" from the definition (below the class). It's illegal. And the missing semicolon at the end of the class declaration, already pointed out.

Comment: You may want to check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/14065

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, exactly!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
class Singleton {

};
 ^^^
```

This! and also,

```
static Singleton *Singleton::itsInstance = 0;
```

replaced with:

```
Singleton *Singleton::itsInstance = 0;
```

You need the `static` only on the declaration not on the definition.

Comment: Aaargh! Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon after your class definition, and you do not want the `static`.

```
static Singleton *Singleton::itsInstance = 0;
```

should be

```
Singleton *Singleton::itsInstance = 0;
```